# Auto scroll to span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an  element that contains (surprise!) an article.

There is a list of tags at the top of the page that are found in the article.
When a user clicks a tag it any matching words in the article are highlighted.

What I am having trouble with is then automatically scrolling to the highlighted word.

Is there any way to do this with javascript/jQuery?

The following is my code to find the word and highlight it:

```
$(".article-tags a.toggle").live("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $p = $this.closest("p");
        if ($p.find("span.highlight").length == 0) {
            $("#viewer .article-body").highlight($this.text());
            $this.highlight($this.text());
            document.getElementById("viewer").scrollTop = $p.find("span.highlight").offsetTop;
        }
        else {
            $("#viewer .article-body").removeHighlight();
            $p.removeHighlight();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work in the first place? I see that this scrolls, so may I assume that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways to accomplish that.

- jQuerys `.animate()` with `scrollTop` set to `elements.offset().top`
- `$(window).scrollTop(element.offset().top);`
- `element.scrollIntoView();`

`.scrollIntoView()` is a native method which you can call on a DOM node directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.highlight').first().prepend('<a class="highlighted" name="hightlighted" />');
window.location.hash = '#highlighted';
```

That should do it. You're adding an anchor just before the element, then scrolling to it. You might want to put in a `$('a.highlighted').remove()` before this to clear any previous additions.